# CSS scrollbar : How to change scrollbar location for div within 2 other dives?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have one inner div in the other outer div for which I call auto scroller, at the same time my outer div in its turn is in other outer div. My scroller is seen only in first outer div, thus as my second div is in the third one, and I want to move the scrolling part on the third div to let the user know that there is scroller, and more information than it is visible from first sight.

Comment: So you only want to add scroll to the third div when the second div overflow? If so why not add auto to the third div instead of the second one, or have on both? There is also the question on how you position and size the divs.

Comment: Actually, my third div contains a lot of different information and adding scrollbar on it scrolls all other components too. And I need scrollbar only on the part of my second div, thus I am searching a way to change location of my second scrollbar.

Comment: Then wouldn't it be easier to have the first div as a sibling of the second div inside the third div instead of as a child of the second div? That is if you have contents beside the first div inside the second one.

Comment: Don't know yet, but I will try it and let you know if it solves my problem, thank you!!

Comment: It is hard to give any good help without knowing the layout of the divs. You could update with a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the basics. You might find this helpful, check out ***CSS layout***: http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/tutorials

Comment: can you provide me some of your code snippet or better a fiddle..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide scrollbar of any element just specify css property
 `overflow:hidden`,
otherwise if you want to show scroll when it's needed then specify `overflow:auto`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but it does not solve the issue I have described.